# average voip compression rates?

Tags: audio, compression, voip, skype

I am running some tests on audio compression and trying out [Skype's Silk](http://developer.skype.com/silk). In their test application I am seeing compression rates of 94%. This seems high, is this a typical rate on Silk? Is this comparable to other audio compression codecs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most speech/telephony codecs run at pretty low bit rates, so 94% does not sound unrealistic, particularly if you're starting with a fairly high sample rate. E.g. 22 kHz 8 bit audio compressed to a 9600 bps stream would be around 94% compression.

Comment: AFAIK VoIP uses only frequencies from ~200-2000Hz. This will give you a good compression due to the fact that you can lower the sample rate a lot (e.g. 8kHz).

Comment: @InsertNickHere: yes, standard telephony bandwidth is only 3 kHz, but there is a lot more that can be done when you are compressing speech only. Modern speech codecs can get down to very low bit rates.